# Retarding Force

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need help with the following question:

A pile-driver has a hammer mass of 1000 kg which is dropped onto a pile from a height of 5 meters. The pile is driven 0.5 meters into the ground. The pile has a mass of 500 kg. Calculate the retarding force exerted by the ground on the combined mass of the pile and hammer.

I have this. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: does your text book not have some similar example problem?

Comment: No. I have no examples to go by. This is why i am stuck.

Comment: with a simple constant force approximation the work is simply `force*(1/2 meter)`.  Note you have  another 1/2 meter times 1500kg potential energy change too.  Of course in the real world a good bit of that energy is dissipated as heat, acoustic energy and so forth.

Comment: I gree with agentp, consider change in kinetic and potential energy and work of retarding force, such solutions you can also found online.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I still can't work it out. I have ordered an engineering book that hopefully will help me get the answer.

Comment: I have edited my question with the answer. Can anyone tel me if it correct? And if not where i have gone wrong please. Thanks.

Comment: Your working is very difficult to follow, e.g. you have "F=1000x9.81" on one line, immediately followed by "F=(500+1000)x9.8+........." on the next. "F" should only have one definition.

Comment: I am sorry about that. The "F = 1000x9.81" is working out the force of the hammer. The "F =(500+1000)x9.81+....." is working out the retarding force of the hammer and pile on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Taking upwards as positive.

$m_1=1000kg,\;h_1=5m $

$m_2=500kg,\;h_2=0m $

$m_3=m_1+m_2=1500kg,\;h_3=-0.5m $

$t_0 = Initial\;State$

$t_1 = At\;Impact$

$t_2 = End\;State$

Since $h_2=0$, the energy of the system at $t_0$, $E_0$, is entirely due to the Gravitational Potential Energy of $m_1$

$$E_0=m_1*g*h_1=1000*9.81*5=49.05kJ$$

At $t_1$, neglecting air resistance, the GPE of $m_1$ has been converted entirely into Kinetic Energy, and as such

$$E_1=E_0=49.05kJ$$

At $t_2$, nothing is moving, and so once again all energy is in the form of GPE

$$E_2=m_3*g*h_3=1500*9.81*-0.5=-7.36kJ$$

The energy change between $t_1$ and $t_2$ is therefore

$$\Delta E=E_2-E_1=-7.36-49.05=-56.41kJ$$

This energy change is brought about by the retarding force acting on $m_3$. Assuming a constant force over the time that $m_3$ is decelerating, and noting that the Work Done took place over a distance of $h_3-h_2=-0.5m$,  the Retarding Force can be calculated:

$$F=\frac{-56.41}{-0.5}=112.8kN$$

Comment: Hello. Thank you for that. I sort of understand it. I am going to read through it a few more times, to totally understand it. You have broken it down, and explained it very well. So the retarding force is 127.5kN ? I thought retarding force was always -. So would be -127.5kN ?

Comment: At the very start of my answer, I defined upwards as positive. The retarding force acts upwards (preventing the hammer from falling downwards). "Retarding" refers merely to the fact that the force causes a deceleration, and has no bearing on the direction (and consequently the sign) of the force.

Comment: Oh right. I was getting confused, because a lot that i have read and watched on YouTube, was placing - for retarding force. Thank you.

Comment: N.B. Since Upwards is defined as positive, the acceleration due to gravity (downwards) is negative, as is the velocity of the hammer at t_1. The Kinetic energy remains positive, however, since it is related to the square of the velocity.

Comment: I think the 112.8 is the answer. Gravity was already accounted for in the potential energy so you don't add it in again.

Comment: You’re absolutely right - edited accordingly... That’ll teach me to try and post answers on my phone during a meeting 

Comment: Thank you for spotting that agentp. And thank you Jonathan R Swift for taking the time to do this for me. I could not find anything that made me understand this. But now i am starting to understand it.